# Пишет не настроено когда подключаюсь к bluetooth наушникам

Tags: bluetooth

Не понимаю как исправить этот момент. До этого все работало, но нажав удалить устройство заново не могу подключиться. До этого нажимая на не настроенные bluetooth наушники все само подключалось

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkyG6.png

Comment: Вы должны публиковать сообщения на английском языке.